# Possible to sum a Cell in two different Google workbooks?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two different Google Sheets. They have 2 different names and are both listed in my Google Drive.
They are identical except they contain individually keyed data. Cell and Colum names are identical.

To recap: These are NOT separate sheets on the SAME Google Sheet workbook, they are separate workbooks.

Is it possible to SUM a Cell in location A1: from Workbook named "This is workbook 1" to another separate URL address "This is workbook 2" ?

I know how to sum across tabs/sheets inside same workbook and that is not my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=IMPORTRANGE("sheet URL or key", "This is workbook 1!A1")

Replace "sheet URL or key" with your source sheet URL and "This is workbook1!A1" with the correct tab name and cell but in both cases keep them in double quotes.

IMPORTRANGE expects text not actual ranges/URLs.

[reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

Comment: To recap and to be clear, there is a long URL address to each of the workbooks and that goes inside the first parenthesis. Then the name of the workbook that is being imported goes inside the second set and where does the sheet name and cell go ? The reference to A1 could be any A1 cell in a multiple sheet/tab workbook.

Comment: @rosa sorry, my bad formatting... have amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok. That worked, had to use format "Sheet1:A1:A1") and permissions across the two workbooks took forever to process (odd, since both are created by me and for me). Had to also shorten all extra URL characters (ie. #edit &gid= etc) from the URL address. Thank you

Comment: @rosa Thanks... could you please mark the answer as accepted (and upvote) so others can find it if required in the future. It really does help the community to do this.

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to do that -- no button visible for "accepted"

Comment: @rosa where the up and down grey triangles are to the left of the answer and the tick check mark is. Hover over them with your mouse and it tells you the function of the symbol. see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers